# How to bind variables into transcluded part

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How to bind variables from directive's scope into transcluded template?

```
app.directive('foo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.num = 5;
        }
    }
})

<div ng-app="app">
    <foo>
        {{num}}
    </foo>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an app module. Also I added a `modified` class so that you could see that the template is being applied:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive('foo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="modified" ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.num = 5;
        }
    }
});
```

**See plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/x9NE6A4kkqspKbO08yhq?p=preview**